# In "The One With The Flashback", why doesn't Rachel comment about Monica's weight(loss)?

Tags: friends

The episode in question is S03E06 "The One With The Flashback". At the bar, Rachel is having a conversation with her friends while Monica & Chandler are hanging out together. A while later Rachel & Monica briefly catchup but Rachel does not comment about Monica's weight loss. It is apparent that they've met after a long time, probably since high school; yet Rachel does not make the obvious comment. What am I missing?

Comment: Not everybody is obsessed with a woman's size.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit While I get your point, she lost more than 110 lbs. If Rachel really *hadn't* seen her since high school, she probably would've said *something* (certainly the more superficial early-era Rachel).

Comment: @Walt: Fair enough; more of a social commentary than a serious response to the question :) I don't watch Friends.

Comment: Just to clarify, the question wasn't intended to stir up any weight related debates. It was purely out of curiosity since in Friends, Monica's pre-loss weight certainly seems to be a running gag :)

Comment: @akdsouza Don't worry. There was *never* any issue with the wording or subject matter of your question

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The episode is from 1996. The flashback takes place [three years prior](http://friends.wikia.com/wiki/The_One_With_The_Flashback), so around **1993**. However, according to [another flashback episode](http://friends.wikia.com/wiki/The_One_With_All_The_Thanksgivings) from season 5, **Monica already lost all that weight by Thanksgiving 1988**, when she and Rachel were still close. So Rachel shouldn't be surprised.